# addListener in the popup doesn't get the message/variable data from content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am sending a jwt variable from content script with this

```
iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify({ data: jwt}), "*");
```

Then, I am trying to read the message in popup.js using this

```
let token;

var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";


eventer(messageEvent, function (e) {
   let jtoken = JSON.parse(e.data);
    token = jtoken.data;
    console.log(token);
}, false);

function getData() {

    console.log(token);
    // Calling API from here
}

// will call the getdata() function from outside and it should be available
getData();
```

In the same popup.js, I have another which uses the token to make api request. But, I am getting undefined in the token variable. However, when I debug using `debugger;`, it shows the token value. Yet, simply calling from the function doesn't get me the token in `token` variable

Comment: @Signo `e` is the event type, iam reading `data` property from it initially and then accessing `data` variable from content script

Answer (score 0):

```
let token;

var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";


eventer(messageEvent, function (e) {
  let jtoken = JSON.parse(e.data);
  token = jtoken.data;
  console.log(token);

  // YOU SHOULD CALL getData() FUNCTION HERE
}, false);

function getData() {

  console.log(token);
  // Calling API from here
}
```

You should call the `getData` function inside `eventer` since you only have the token available after it is set inside that function.

Comment: doesn't work. can't call the functional from outside if i declare the function `getData` inside the `eventer` function callback.

Comment: if there is any way i can halt function from executing unless the `token` variable is available. like with `async await`. but i couldn't get it to work

Comment: I don't tell you to declare the `getData` function inside the `eventer`. I say that you should CALL it from there, I think you shouldn't change or move your `getData` definition.

Comment: but i need to call `getData` from outside as well from other `click` events.

Comment: What if you set a message listener with an appropiate callback for every place you need the token? Just thinking out loud

Comment: again the same weird error that the variable is undefined. tried it with chrome.storage as well but still the same thing.